# Variational Autoencoder TIme Series

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, autoencoder

Can anyone suggest a blog where Variational Autoencoder has been used for time series forecasting?

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=r1cLblgCZ

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look at this paper and references therein
[Variational Encoding of Complex Dynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.08576)

Answer (score 0):

[Variational-LSTM autoencoder to forecast the spread of coronavirus across the globe](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0246120)

A novel variational-LSTM Autoencoder model to predict the spread of coronavirus for each country across the globe. This deep Spatio-temporal model does not only rely on historical data of the virus spread but also includes factors related to urban characteristics represented in locational and demographic data (such as population density, urban population, and fertility rate), an index that represents the governmental measures and response amid toward mitigating the outbreak.

[image]
*variational LSTM autoencoder model*